# a good library for calculating sha-256 in c++

Tags: c++, sha256

I'm trying to find a good library for calculating sha256. I found already a lot of options

crypto++ : http://www.cryptopp.com/

openSSL: http://www.openssl.org/

MIRACL: http://www.shamus.ie/

I would much prefer a library that's well-known, widely industrially used and works on all  operating systems, rather than the most efficient one.

What do you recommend for me? (feel free to recommend on a library that I didn't mention here).

Comment: `openssl` is very widely used.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Mozilla's Network Security Services](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/), which has better documentation than OpenSSL, and also has SHA-256 implementations.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider [cryptlib](http://www.cryptlib.com/)

**Works on all operating systems**

Cryptlib is supplied as source code for AMX, BeOS, ChorusOS, DOS, DOS32, eCOS, µC/OS-II, embedded Linux, FreeRTOS/OpenRTOS, IBM MVS, µITRON, Macintosh/OS X, OS/2, PalmOS, RTEMS, Tandem, ThreadX, a variety of Unix versions (including AIX, Digital Unix, DGUX, FreeBSD/NetBSD/OpenBSD, HP-UX, IRIX, Linux, MP-RAS, OSF/1, QNX, SCO/UnixWare, Solaris, SunOS, Ultrix, and UTS4), uClinux, VM/CMS, VxWorks, Windows 3.x, Windows 95/98/ME, Windows CE/PocketPC/SmartPhone, Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista/Windows 7 (32- and 64-bit versions), VDK, and Xilinx XMK.  cryptlib’s highly portable nature means that it is also being used in a variety of custom embedded system environments.

**Widely industrially used**

see [Clients](http://www.cryptlib.com/security-software/clients-users)

It's not free for commercial use, though.

Comment: Thank you all very much, my final decision is to use the openSSL library

Answer (score 1):

I've recently needed a small library to do some hashing.
After lots of searching, I found this little one : https://create.stephan-brumme.com/hash-library/ .
Its a tiny single-headered library (or bunch of standalone implementations really) that one can use. it supports sha1,sha256, sha3, etc.
Just include the header you need and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [s2n](https://github.com/awslabs/s2n): a C99 implementation of the TLS/SSL protocols that is designed to be simple, small, fast, and with security as a priority. It is released and licensed under the Apache License 2.0.

[s2n hash functions](https://github.com/awslabs/s2n/blob/5357a708aedefcc905462a689e668c93f3b877ab/crypto/s2n_hash.h).

Answer (score 0):

See also the implementation in Mbed TLS: https://tls.mbed.org/